# Delete multiple items in array when position (index) is unknown

Tags: mongodb

I have the folowing Mongo db schema :

```
"Price_History" : [
    {
        "pr" : 62,
        "BookingDateTo" : "2014-08-05T18:41:35",
        "CollectionDate" : "2014-07-22T18:41:35",
        "Vendor" : "test",
        "BookingDateFrom" : "2014-08-04T18:41:35"
    },
    {
        "BookingDateFrom" : "2014-08-04T23:01:37",
        "BookingDateTo" : "2014-08-05T23:01:37",
        "pr" : 62,
        "Vendor" : "test",
        "CollectionDate" : "2014-07-19T23:01:37"
    }
],
```

this should be:

```
"Price_History" : [
    {
        "pr" : 62,
        "BookingDateTo" : "2014-08-05T18:41:35",
        "CollectionDate" : "2014-07-22T18:41:35",
        "Vendor" : "Trv",
        "BookingDateFrom" : "2014-08-04T18:41:35"
    },
```

The query should delete multiple items in an array if Price_History.CollectionDate is older then 2014-07-19T23:01:37 
Finally the query should update all documents

is that posible ?

Comment: Sure, but this works best if you've made a best effort to figure this out from the documentation first. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/#array

Comment: Hi JohnnyHK my homework already done, db.coll.update( {}, { $pullAll : { "Price_History.CollectionDate" :{ $gte : "2014-07-19T23:01:37" }} }) but unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: or db.coll.update( {}, { $pull : { "Price_History : { CollectionDate" : { $gte : "2014-07-19T23:01:37" }} }, {multi: true} ) doesn't work to.

Comment: or db.coll.update( {}, { $pull : { "Price_History : { CollectionDate" :  "2014-07-22T18:41:35" } }, false, true ) doesn't work to.

Comment: Thanks for adding your attempts so we could see where you might be going wrong.  Next time edit your question to add them as they don't format well in comments.

Answer (score 2):

You're close, but you've got some mis-matched quotes in your keys which is breaking things and it should be:

```js
db.coll.update({}, 
    {$pull: {Price_History: {CollectionDate: {$lte : "2014-07-19T23:01:37"}}}},
    {multi: true})
```

I also changed it to use `$lte` since you were looking for "older than".  Using `$pull` instead of `$pullAll` is also important here as `$pullAll` only removes elements that match exactly while `$pull` performs a query match.

Comment: thx JohnnyHK, my solution is: db.coll.update({}, {$pull: {Price_History: {CollectionDate: { "$lte" : "2014-07-19T23:01:37"} }}}, false, true)